# Why is beryllium 8 ($ ^8_4 Be $) such an unstable element?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, radioactivity, half-life

And by unstable I mean a half life of $ 6.7 \cdot 10^{-17} s$.

And what is exactly the criterion used to say an element is stable of unstable? Where do we draw the line?

Comment: Be8 is happier as two He4 atoms - total binding energy is higher. Stable means it will not decay spontaneously.

Comment: @JonCuster This sould be an answer!

Comment: "It will not decay spontaneously" as in "we calculate it'll not" or as in "we never detected the decay" or as in "if the decay gives a half-life that exceeds x amount of time to happen it is considered stable"?

Comment: I was wondering if the situation for $^{212}\mathrm{Po}$ is similar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One point of view is that the state of two alpha particles is not bound. A bit like the system of two protons or system of two neutrons.

The other point of view is that once you form a resonance (could be viewed as a kind of a ground state of $^{8}Be$) it immediately (in the moment of formation?) *"sees"* an energetically more favored state of two separate alpha particles and -since the interaction is *strong* - it can decay very fast to the final state (see also Fermi golden rule).

**Addendum:**

If the interaction $<fin|H|init>$ between the initial and final states (hypothetically) was electromagnetic, the half-life *of the state* could be like $10^{-12} s$ and longer *(if the transition multipole is too high or the two states are too different)*. These are the times one frequently finds when an excited nucleus cools down by $\gamma$ emission.

**Criterion:**
(I forgot)

Stability is usually ment as a stability against a decay. Look at https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html - all black are stable, they are not too many. What you mean is probably "stable or radioactive" or something in this sense. Many can decay by $\beta+$ or $\beta-$, but from the perspective of *a strong interaction*, they are *quite* stable. You can define unbound nuclei and one speaks about *neutron drip line* or *proton drip line*. Alpha decay of heavy nuclei is a bit different process to mention it here.

Comment: MathJax pro-tip: use `$\langle \rangle$` or even `$\left< \right>$` to make bras and kets with better kerning.

Comment: I really wanted to associate a number to word "stable". Could be a concept, though. But I don't really know against what to compare. I mean... What is the standard for "stable" against which we compare other elements?

Comment: Associate "stable" to *infinite life*

Comment: I know what you wanted...but if you assign a time$=10^{-15}$, then you always risk, that somebody finds an elmg. transition faster than that (they get faster with bigger energy difference) and you risk that somebody finds a case where final state for strong interaction is so wierd, that it takes really long.

Comment: @jaromrax That kind of thing has happened. From the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_elements_by_stability_of_isotopes)  *"Of the first 82 elements in the periodic table, 80 have isotopes considered to be stable. The 83rd element, bismuth, was traditionally regarded as having the heaviest stable nuclide, bismuth-209, but in 2003 researchers in Orsay, France, measured the half-life of $^{209}\mathrm{Bi}$ to be $1.9×10^{19}$ years."*

Comment: https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v422/n6934/pdf/nature01541.pdf?origin=ppub - yes, alpha decay...

Comment: @dmckee It was exactly that article that made me ask this question. I was actually surprised when I saw it had no comparison or artificial definition for stable. I was also trying to see if the definition is based on the "maximum measurable half-life than can be experimentally measured" (if that exists), but fell short to find it when I saw that $^{180m}Ta$ is expected to have a half-life of at least $10^{15}yr$ but was never observed to decay. So I guess the best answer given is that you can calculate, but nobody ever thought about how to define well enough what is objectively "stable".

Comment: And that is kinda cool as it is indeed difficult to think about a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the decay energy of 8 Be is far less than that of 238 U it has a short half life due to the extremely shallow Coulomb barrier. This means that the pre formed alpha particle has an extremely high probability of escaping (as you remember, the probability of the alpha particle tunneling has to do with the difference between the KE of the alpha particle and the Coulomb potential), compared to that of U. And of all compound nuclei formed of alphas, 8 Be is the only one with more mass energy than the rest. For example, 12 C has less mass energy than 8 Be, hence why it's stable.